# if $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) \sin (c x)\;dx = 0, \forall c \in \mathbb{R}$ then $f$ must be a even function.

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis

Suppose $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) \sin (c x)\;dx = 0$, $\forall c \in \mathbb{R}$. Then $f$ must be a even function.

I'm struggling on proving this affirmation. I know that the converse is clearly true. Also, know that $f$ can always be rewritten as as a sum of an even and an odd function $g$ and $h$, lets say. So the integral of $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) \sin (c x)\;dx$ becomes just the integral of $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} h(x) \sin (c x)\;dx$ which is also zero, but i dont see how to proceed.

Any hints? Thanks!

Comment: Use the substitution $x\leftrightarrow -x$

Comment: @NinadMunshi Respectfully, what would that accomplish?

Comment: @BrunoB add the two integrals together. What happens to the integrand?

Answer (score 1):

If $g(x)=f(x)-f(-x)$ then the assumption implies that the Fourier transform of $g$ is $0$. So $g=0$ almost everywhere, i.e.  $f(x)=f(-x)$ for almost every $x$. If further we assume that $f$ is continuous we may conclude that $f$ is even.